# Small signal model of Boost DCM

Tags: boost, small-signal

I read the Christophe Basso [APEC 2013](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202013.pdf) and on page 90 I have some questions:
[image]

1.) How to get equation 2, because I don't know where B1 current comes from.
2.) what is B1 current meaning

Comment: B1 current is generated by B1 itself ... it is an ideal current source

Comment: @jsotola I know it was generated by itself, I want to know how to get this current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I am working on these complicated circuits, I always to try to simplify equations and rearrange the whole thing in a friendly shape. This is what I've done from the founding circuit shown below:

[image]

The current source connected between terminals *a* and *p* includes a reference to \$N\$ which involves the DCM duty ratios \$d_1\$ and \$d_2\$. I thus would like to replace this source by a single equation without reference to other sources. In this expression, the current monitored by the dummy source VIC is actually current \$I_c\$. If I manipulate equations for \$N\$ and \$d_2\$, I have:

[image]

If I now multiply this expression by I(VIC) or actually \$I_c\$, I have:

[image]

The voltage \$V_{ac}\$ is \$V_{ac}=V_{(a)}-V_{(c)}=-V_{(c)}\$ because terminal *a* is grounded. Therefore, the final current source is:

[image]

You could also remove the negative sign and revert the current source, it is the same. All these models are explained in details in my [new book](https://stairwaypress.com/product/transfer-functions-of-switching-converters/) describing small-signal models of switching converters. Going through the details and learning how the transfer functions are derived is the best way to understand loop compensation later on: you're on the right track!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know how to do!

Comment: Your book look likes great.

Comment: Glad if I could help you and good luck with small-signal modeling: this is important and often overlooked so an interesting skill to acquire!

Comment: I am curious about one thing. It is ok to use this method to derive the interleave DC/DC converter?

Comment: The small-signal model does not change for an interleaved dc-dc. You simply scale the inductor by the number of phases.

Comment: I see the paper, the interleaved dc-dc just scale the inductor, the paper use SSA to proof, if I want to use PWM switch to proof how should I do can you give me a hint?

Comment: I don't have further hints beside the approach I documented for the single-phase dc-dc. Why would you want to further complicate things? Scale the inductor in the averaged model then run a SIMPLIS simulation using one my 60+ [new templates](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) and you will see that it works.

Comment: Sir, let me ask another question, the PWM switch model can derive the flyback 、forward which have the transformer? If it can use the turn ratio to replace the voltage source?

Comment: Yes, of course, it is all described in my upcoming book.